# constrained_layout=True moves one column deeper

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I used constrained_layout= True multiple times and everything worked good... now I added a second Colorbar an i get somthing like that:
[image]

How I can fix this? I want the same hight and space between the bars and plots.

```
        colorbar_shrink = 0.6
        pad=-0.15
        fig, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(15, 10), constrained_layout=True,
                         sharey=True, subplot_kw={'projection': crs})
  #      fig.tight_layout()
 #       fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.01)
 #       fig.set_constrained_layout_pads(w_pad=0.02, h_pad=0.02, hspace=-0.2,
#                                wspace=0.2)
        fig.suptitle('Bla', y=1.01)
#        fig.set_constrained_layout_pads(w_pad=0, h_pad=0.05,hspace=0.1, wspace=0.2)
        axlist = axarr.flatten()
        for ax in axlist:
            plot_background(ax)

        print('First .')
        levels = np.linspace(0, 2, 10)
        cf1 = axlist[0].contourf(lon_2d, lat_2d, aod_dust_550nm, cmap='Oranges',
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=0, levels=levels, extend='both')
        cf2 = axlist[0].contourf(lon_2d, lat_2d, tq, cmap='Blues', vmin=0.0001, vmax=10 ,
                levels=tq_lev, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(),
                transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=0, extend='max')
        cb1 = fig.colorbar(cf1,  ax=axlist[0], orientation='horizontal', format='%.1f',
                                shrink=colorbar_shrink, pad=pad)
        cb2 = fig.colorbar(cf2,  ax=axlist[0], orientation='vertical', #format='%.4f',
                               shrink=colorbar_shrink)
        cb1.set_label('Dust optical depth @550nm',labelpad=-45, fontsize=12)
        cb2.ax.set_ylabel('TQ in kg m$^{-2}$')
        cb2.formatter = LogFormatter()
        cb2.set_ticks([1e-4,1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1e0, 10])
        cb2.update_ticks()

        print('Second..')
        # Upper right plot - Wind and Windspeed
        levels = np.linspace(0.0, 50.0, 50)
        cf2 = axlist[1].contourf(lon_2d, lat_2d, windspeed_900, levels=levels,
                cmap='jet', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree() ,zorder=0, extend='max')
        #Every n-th quiver
        wind_slice = (slice(None, None, 15), slice(None, None, 15))
        c2 = axlist[1].quiver(lon_2d[wind_slice], lat_2d[wind_slice] ,
                u_300.values[wind_slice] , v_300.values[wind_slice],
                color='black', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        cb2 = fig.colorbar(cf2,  ax=axlist[1], orientation='horizontal',format='%i',
                shrink=colorbar_shrink)#, pad=paddy)
        cb2.set_label('Wind speed in m s-1 @900hPa',labelpad=-45, fontsize=12)
        plt.quiverkey(c2, 0.99, -0.16, 10,'velocity (10 m s$^{-1}$)',
                labelpos='W',transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), color='r')

      #  plt.show()
```

THanks a lot.

Comment: You are drawing maps, and as such they have fixed aspect ratios.  constrained_layout doesn't care about the part of the axes that gets shrunk to maintain the aspect ratio, so you get weird results like this.   Perhaps make a self-contained example, and then play with the panchor kwarg of the Colorbar.

Comment: Hi Jody, thank you for the infos. After changing and testing... the same results are printed. Is there a nother way to resize the size of the complete figure?

Comment: You can resize by hand `figsize=(w, h)`, and there is a PR in Matplotlib to add the ability for automatically fixing this problem, though I'm not sure it will work for your case.  However, the `panchor` is what you really want to look at.

Comment: Now it works... but the left colorbars are shifted to the left... is there a way to use something like pad to adust it to the left or to the right?

Comment: @S.Kocic. Probably?  But its hard to test and give suggestions without an example I can run

Comment: I fixed it... by playing arround with gridspacing of the complete plot. Thanks